# How to loop through / recurse subdirectories

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, recursion, cmd, windows-10

I have a batch file that copies files from a source folder to a target folder, (with some logic).

The .bat file:

```
@echo off

:: Set the source and target folders
set source=E:\Files\VersionFiles\CodeITv4.19.1.5
set target=E:\ProductionApp\WorkOrder\CTM_TEST_ManualWorkOrder

:: Get the name of the last subfolder in the target folder, which will be used as the ServiceName
for %%i in ("%target%") do set ServiceName=%%~nxi

:: Display the ServiceName
echo The ServiceName is %ServiceName%

:: Check if the service with ServiceName exists
sc query "%ServiceName%" | find "SERVICE_NAME" >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    :: Service exists, stop it if running
    sc query "%ServiceName%" | find "STATE" | find /i "RUNNING" >nul
    if %errorlevel%==0 (
        echo Service is running, stopping service...
        net stop "%ServiceName%"
        timeout /t 5
    ) else (
        echo Service is not running.
    )
) else (
    :: Service does not exist
    echo Service does not exist.
)

del "%target%\%ServiceName%.exe" /Q
del "%target%\%ServiceName%.exe.config" /Q

xcopy /s /y "%source%\*" "%target%"
ren "%target%\CodeIT.exe" "%ServiceName%.exe"
ren "%target%\CodeIT.exe.config" "%ServiceName%.exe.config"

:: Start the service if it exists
sc query "%ServiceName%" | find "SERVICE_NAME" >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo Starting the service...
    net start "%ServiceName%"
) else (
    echo Service does not exist. Skipping service start.
)

pause
```

This works perfect. Now I would like to extend the batch file to do the same thing for multiple target folders.

Lets say target=Production

```
Production\Printer\**Printer1**
Production\Printer\**Printer2**
Production\scanner\**scanner1**
Production\scanner\**scanner1**
Production\Scale\PrintModeScale\**PrintModeScale1**
```

This is where my struggle starts. I don't know how to make it loop through app folders inside the root folder.

Any help/guides would be appreciated.

Comment: Do not use `::`-style comments in loops - use `rem` as `::` will break the loop. (jumps out at first look)

Comment: Surely `for %%i in ("%target%") do set ServiceName=%%~nxi` should be `for /f "eol=? delims=" %%i in ('dir "%target%" /a:d /b /o:n 2^>nul') do set "ServiceName=%%~nxi"` too! Then if you wanted to recurse subdirectories, you'd just use the `/s`ubdirectory option, `for /f "eol=? delims=" %%i in ('dir "%target%" /a:d /b /o:n /s 2^>nul') do (...`!